# Google Map Framework add using cocoapods in Ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoapods

I am using cocoapods to add dependencies of all framework. I am facing a issue with google map sdk. I have made pod file and put below command for download libray.

```
    pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.9'
```

Also In additionally ,It's automatically added line into pod resource shell script for path

```
    install_resource "Google-Maps-iOS-SDK/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle"
```

It's working. But it couldn't copy googleMaps.bundle from googleMaps.framework to my project.and giving me error runtime see below.

```
    GMSServicesException', reason: 'GoogleMaps.bundle requires 
   Google Maps SDK for iOS to be part  of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources
```

Answer (score 0):

May be adding resource_bundles in your pods' specs could help.

Please refer:http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resource_bundles